# push_back(*obj) is calling destructor and is causing SDL_BlitSurface to crash

Tags: c++, vector, sdl

I am new to SDL programming in C++ and so I'm working on a simple Invaders game.

In it I have several classes, one of which is of course the Alien class. The destructor of Alien calls for **SDL_FreeSurface(SPRITEOFALIEN)**, in order to delete the object.

I also have a vector in the Game class, and all works well if there is only one Alien, **however** as soon as I spawn another Alien and I call **push_back** to add it to the vector, the destructor gets called, and so when it comes to actually drawing the vector of Aliens, SDL_BlitSurface crashes the program.

Sample code:

```
vector<Alien> aliens;

// More code.... and eventually

if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_a) //Add Alien! Debugging
{
    alien = new Alien(150, 0); // Alien* alien 
    aliens.push_back(*alien);
}
// Some more code... advancing the aliens, etc...

std::vector<Alien>::iterator it2;
for (it2 = aliens.begin(); it2 != aliens.end(); ++it2)
    SDL_BlitSurface(it2->getSprite(), 0, screen, it2->getRect()); /// CRASH, FIXME
```

I looked up other similar questions, but they all suggested having a fixed sized vector, which I don't think is a good solution for my case, given that there should be an arbitrary number of aliens (and missiles too, I have the same problem for them).

I also know that it happens because when push_back is called, the vector is copied to a new bigger sized vector and that is why the destructors are called. Yet for some reason, the drawObjects function catches the OLD vector and crashes...

Is there a way around this?

Alien Class Definition:

```
#include "alien.h"

Alien::Alien(int x, int y)
{
    rect.x = x; // x-pos
    rect.y = y; // y-pos
    sprite = SDL_LoadBMP("alien.bmp");

}

Alien::~Alien()
{
    SDL_FreeSurface(sprite)
    printf("Deleted Alien\n");
}


void Alien::move()
{

    rect.y += SPEED;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to use C++11 and move semantics. `aliens.emplace_back(150, 0)`. Or if you don't have C++11 then you need to use `vector<Alien*>`.

Comment: Do not use new to create an object to be stored and owned by a container (any new must be paired with a delete to avoid memory leaks). In addition test your 'Alien' class.

Comment: Why this dynamic allocation? It's completely needless and you end up with a memory leak. Furthermore, it looks like `Alien` has memory problems, but since we cannot see the definition...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit looks like java/C# school.

Comment: You are not storing the object in your vector, you are copying it, and the original is destroyed. Use a `vector<Alien*>` instead.

Comment: Added the definition.
@cdhowie I tried that, and the problem persisted.

Comment: @ch0l1n3 You should (a) delete the default copy-constructor and copy-assignment operators, (b) implement move-construction and move-assignment, (c) alter your destructor so it doesn't call `SDL_FreeSurface()` if `this` was used to move-construct/assign another object, and (d) don't use `new` here because you don't need it at all. Better yet you should create a new class that provides these RAII semantics for a single SDL surface and then use that from `Alien` -- you'll then get the correct behavior by default.

Comment: @Havenard: The original is _not_ destroyed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No, but the copy in the vector is destroyed when the vector reallocates.  The unexpected call to the destructor, therefore freeing the surface, is indeed the behavior OP is seeing.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, of course. I am pointing out to Havenard, who claimed that the `new`'d object is copied into the vector then destroyed. It is copied into the vector but assuredly _not_ destroyed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is likely coming from copies of `Alien`. When a copy is destructed it will destroy the surface resource being shared by all of the copies. If multiple copies are being made when you call `push_back()` -- and I would bet that at least two copies are -- then on this line alone you double-free the `SDL_Surface *` and this is likely causing the crash.

I would strongly suggest defining a type *specifically* to manage surfaces in an RAII fashion, and then using that from `Alien` as you'll get the proper semantics by default.

For example:

```
struct SDLSurfaceDeleter
{
    void operator()(SDL_Surface * p) const
    {
        if (p) { SDL_FreeSurface(p); }
    }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, SDLSurfaceDeleter> UniqueSDLSurface;
```

Now in your `Alien` class you have:

```
private:
    UniqueSDLSurface sprite;
```

And in your constructor:

```
sprite = UniqueSDLSurface(SDL_LoadBMP("alien.bmp"));
```

(Or, better yet, initialize it in the initializer list: `sprite(SDL_LoadBMP("alien.bmp"))`. With the initializer list approach you construct the `UniqueSDLSurface` object right the first time; with the assignment approach you default-construct it and then move-assign a new object. Both will work, but the initializer list approach is cleaner.)

Finally, remove the `Alien` destructor.  Now, the `Alien` class should be automatically movable, but not copyable.  If you get any compile-time errors about copying `Alien` objects you need to fix those; they were the source of your problem in the first place, and with this code the compiler simply *won't let copying happen anymore*, which is a good thing!

In a proper C++ standard library, `std::vector` will move objects when possible during a reallocation, so now you'll be able to use it properly because it will be moving your `Alien` objects to their new destination instead of copying them.

As a side note, you could similarly use `std::shared_ptr` to create a shared surface, where the surface is freed when the last `std::shared_ptr` is destroyed.  This might make more sense here since all `Alien` objects use the same source bitmap; you could load it once and then share it among all of the instances:

```
std::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface> make_shared_surface(SDL_Surface * surface)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface>(surface, SDLSurfaceDeleter());
}
```

Further, here you leak memory, because you don't `delete` the object you allocated with `new`:

```
alien = new Alien(150, 0); // Alien* alien 
aliens.push_back(*alien);
```

But you don't need to do this anyway, since you can do:

```
aliens.push_back(Alien(150, 0));
```

Or, better yet:

```
aliens.emplace_back(150, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this very soon! (classes...) and let you know!

Comment: How can I access the sprite as an SDL_Surface?
I need it in order to draw the sprite using SDL_BlitSurface(args).

**Edit: Figured it out! I used sprite.get()

Comment: However, how can I have multiple SDLSurfaceDeleters?
If I have a header file named SDLDeleter.h and add your structure and the unique pointer, the compiler says I redifined it, whenever I use it for the missiles class.

Comment: GOT IT!
Just needed to use a #ifndef SDL_DELETER statement! 
So strange... Anyway, thank you, you got it right!

Comment: @ch0l1n3 The `#ifndef` thing is an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) and it's a standard thing -- you should have them in all of your headers!

Comment: Didn't know that! I will fix my headers then!

Answer (score 2):

First of all the fact that you have issue when your objects are copied points that most probably you broke the "rule of three" -http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

if your objects cannot be copied you should prohibit copy and/or move (making copy/move ctor private for example) at least then compiler will tell you if there is a problem and you try to copy them.

Now to avoid copying your objects in a vector you need to reserve enough space in vector and call `emplace` upon creation if you can use C++11. Or you should keep objects by pointers. Your code where you create instance dynamically suggest you or somebody else planned to do so, but for whatever reason put it into `vector<Alien>` by value. Also you should not keep objects by raw pointers in the `vector` (unless you experienced enough and know what you are doing) so you should use smart pointer, either standard if you use C++11 or from boost or similar library otherwise:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Alien> AlienPtr;
typedef std::vector<AlientPtr> Aliens;
Aliens aliens;

if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_a) //Add Alien! Debugging
{
    aliens.push_back( std::make_shared<Alien>( 150, 0 ) );
}
```

Comment: *"if your objects cannot be copied you should prohibit copy/move"* -- There's rarely a reason to prohibit moving.  Especially if copying isn't possible, you *should* implement moving.

Comment: @cdhowie updated answer, I meant prohibit either copy or move or both depends on situation.

Answer (score 2):

The essential issue with a vector of varying size is that when the size increases, the vector may have to reallocate and put all its contents in a new location.  This will copy all the existing contents and then destroy the old objects.

Since you don't want your object destroyed (that cleans up the SDL surface), we need to arrange that the vector copies and destroys something else.  It could be a raw pointer, but a much better approach is to use a smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr`.

Try this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Alien>> aliens;
```

...

```
if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_a) //Add Alien! Debugging
{
    alien = new Alien(150, 0); // Alien* alien 
    aliens.emplace_back(alien);
}
```

Then when you use it, you'll need to dereference it...

```
for (std::unique_ptr<Alien>& that_alien : aliens)
    SDL_BlitSurface(that_alien->getSprite(), 0, screen, that_alien->getRect());
```

This avoids ever using the broken Alien copy constructor.  You should go one step further and disable that to make sure it is never called by accident.  In your class definition, add:

```
class Alien
{
// add one of the two lines below
    private: Alien(const Alien&) = delete; // if your compiler has = delete implemented
    private: Alien(const Alien&); // this is almost as good
};
```

Comment: Tried this but the push_back alien is barfing.
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Alien> >::push_back(Alien*&)’|

I have never used unique_ptr, so I think it's because I'm missing the proper way to call it!

Comment: OK try using emplace_back instead of push_pack

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the `Alien` class allocates some pointers using new, frees them upon destruction and does not have a copy constructor. In that case, the default implementation is to copy the pointers, not to allocate new copies of the objects. You should write a copy constructor for `Alien` that does precisely that. If you imagine that `member` is the only member of `Alien` (of class `Member`), that would look like that:

```
Alien(const Alien & a) {
  member = new Member(*member);
}
```

Of course, if in turn `Member` allocates some objects, you should make the right copy constructor there too.

Comment: He said exactly what is the resource being managed (an SDL surface).  Trying to copy that isn't a very good idea.

Comment: Of course it should, leaking SDL surface is bad.  He has a non-copyable object, which is really not that rare.  For an example in the C++ library, see `std::fstream`.

Comment: What I meant is that smarted memory management is needed, such as pointers to shared data. But in any case, the unique pointer approach is probably the way to go.